# Add a user to sudoers file, for just one service

Tags: services, sudo

I want to add a user to the sudoers file so that it can only start, stop and restart a particular service.

I am using Debian and can access the sudoers file using `sudo visudo`, I am stumped now though on how to set up this one user to be limited to one service.

Comment: This should probably be moved to unix & linux stackexchange site. I flagged it to get moved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
root@megatron# visudo
```

Append following line (where megatron is your hostname)

```
jakenoble megatron=/etc/init.d/httpd start, /etc/init.d/httpd stop,/etc/init.d/httpd restart, /sbin/services httpd restart
```

Save and close the file. You have to type following command:

```
jakenoble@megatron$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

---

You must list the full command you want someone to run for visudo to allow it.

For example, given the line in `/etc/sudoers`

```
 %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Users can only RESTART (`-r`) the machine, they cannot HALT (`-h`) it.

Comment: That makes sense, I will try it

Comment: Good summary, lots of questions recently that involve `visudo`.

Comment: I wish sudoers had possibility to add several commands in one line like `jakenoble megatron=/etc/init.d/httpd {start,stop,restart}`. It would decrease amount of duplication...